# "onCreateOptionsMenu" always throwing exception

Tags: android, android-menu

I am creating onCreateOptionsMenu I'm getting the menu inflater exception. I have tried everything available on this website and other sources. Actually I'm following Notepad tutorial available on Android site. I tried to create a menu in my application from scratch, its giving the same error.

simple menu code below

```
private int searchBtnId = Menu.FIRST;  
private int group1Id = 1;  

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    menu.add(group1Id,searchBtnId ,searchBtnId,"Search");  
    //menu.setGroupVisible(1, false);  
    openOptionsMenu();
    return true;  
}



    02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.demo.notepad2/com.android.demo.notepad2.NoteEdit}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at com.android.demo.notepad2.NoteEdit.onCreate(NoteEdit.java:32)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
02-04 12:09:18.544: E/AndroidRuntime(396):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: ok.. somehow I am able to figured this out. Its working.

Comment: now I am receiving this error

Comment: to the best of my knowledege I can understand that It is saying the intent is not starting, and I dont know y..

Comment: post line 32 in NoteEdit.java: